# How can I zip or rar files listed in a text file from the Windows command line?

Tags: command-line, compression, zip, filenames

I'm using a batch script to output filenames with specific attributes to a `.txt` file, in this case older than 30 days. I'd like to then zip or rar those files that are listed in the `.txt` file.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Can you update your question to clarify what operating system you are using?

Comment: Windows 7 to create the batch, i'd like it to be cross compatible with other Windows editions though. Thanks

Comment: At the moment, I'm outputting full path to txt file, so it looks a little like this;

Comment: C:\folder\file.txt
C:\folder\file2.txt 

and so on..

Comment: Could you possibly edit your question to add the current code that prints in the txt file? That might help us updating it to zip/rar your files...

Answer (score 3):

According to 7z command line options:

```
Usage: 7z <command> [<switches>...] <archive_name> [<file_names>...]
       [<@listfiles...>]
```

Since you've already have the list of files you can just use `@` for that file. For example to compress files in `filelist.txt` into test.zip, use the following command

```
7z a test.zip @filelist.txt
```

I've tried that and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

For RAR, just specify the file list in that place in the command line where you usually specify the list of files, but prefix it with "@" character.

For example, you have a list of files that you need to archive, in the `list-of-files.txt`, one file

```
rar a archive-file @list-of-files.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

RAR for MSDOS

ls.txt content :

```
C:\Users\xpacio\Desktop\001\foo.bin
C:\Users\xpacio\Desktop\002\foo.dat
```

in desktop exist :

```
001/foo.bin
001/bar.dat
002/foo.dat
002/bar.bin
```

Command:

```
rar a -m5 -ep1 -cu -n@ls.txt result.rar C:\Users\xpacio\Desktop\
```

the comand, make a rar file named result.rar in the actual path.
the rar contents:

```
   001/FOO.BIN
   002/FOO.DAT
```

parameters:

```
-m5  max level of compression
-ep1 cut the path depth 
-cu  convert to UPPERCASE
-n@ls.txt listo of files to process
```

Comment: who told you that RAR is for MS-DOS? It can't even run in DOS. [Windows cmd and MS-DOS are completely different things](https://superuser.com/a/1411173/241386)