# How to list hardware in DOS?

Tags: ms-dos

I have a PC running MS-DOS (i.e. no Windows). How can I retrieve a list of all hardware present on the PC? Something like Everest for Windows, or something simpler, like `lspci` from Linux.

Comment: There's no `cmd.exe` in MS-DOS.  You've already confused one person with that error.

Comment: that was before OP clarified that he really meant DOS, removing it

Comment: DOS in itself is not aware of PCI as such. You may be able to do it with some 3rd party DOS utility. You might also look into booting Linux. What is currently stopping you from booting Linux? What kind of access do you currently have to the machine? (Such as ability to copy files to the HDD.)

Comment: nowhere did the OP say cmd.exe where did you get that from @JdeBP ?

Comment: +1 for asking what you meant. He wrote "I mean a really DOS system, there's no Windows available"

Comment: Well it was definitely in the question when I read it.  And the person who put it there has definitely confused one person with that error.  (-:

Comment: IN the answers below I see  lot of answers for the PCI parts.  But the BX chips is from an era where motherboards also had ISA cards (e.g. an Adaptec 1542fc or a NE2000). I am missing how to detect those.

Comment: Granted, the answer probably is 'no way to detect' or 'check you paper list which also shows how jumpers on the cards are configured with IRQs, IO ports etc. But BX era is close enough that use of classic (non pnp) ISA cards is realistic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [**`HWiNFO`**](http://www.hwinfo.com/), available for DOS.

> Hardware Info (HWiNFO) is a powerful system information utility
>   designed especially for detection of hardware.

Download [`here`](http://www.hwinfo.com/download.php)(Look *HWiNFO v5.5 for DOS*).

[image]

Comment: The classical utility for this on an MS-DOS distribution would be `MSD`.

Comment: Don't forget *Ralf Brown's* [`PCICFG`](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ralf/files.html), it's about as close to `lspci` as you can get.

Answer (score 2):

### SOLUTION-1:

There is a free tool from FreeDOS, which is very similar to 'lspci'. This tool should be compatible with MS-DOS. Download it from: http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/micro/pc-stuff/freedos/files/distributions/1.2/repos/pkg-html/pcisleep.html

And use it as:

```
pcisleep L
```

this will list devices on PCI bus...

```
addr vendor:type  vendor description
-----------------------------------
xxxx [8086:7111]  Intel  IDE Controller
xxxx [9999:9999]  AMD    LAN Ethernet
...
```

## SOLUTION-2 (only for Network Cards on PCI):

There is a free tool, called 'nicscan.exe' which scans PCI for Network cards available. Donwload from here: https://www.jumpjet.info/Application-Software/DOS/Hardware/2/NICSCAN/NICSCAN.zip

```
nicscan.exe
```

it will list something like:

```
Bus: 2     Device: 0          Function: 0

PCI vendor: 1022 = Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
PCI device: 2000 = 79c790 [PCnet32 LANCE]
```

The result shown above is the VMWare NIC AMD 79c790 10Mbps

Answer (score 0):

Another option (for DOS) may be Quarterdeck's QEMM may have Manifest (mft.exe)

The term "system profiler" may be useful when searching for additional alternatives for general hardware detection.  Additionally, there are specific methods to detect specific types of hardware, so if you need something specific, do clarify.

It looks like some more software for ports may be found from [I/O port programs](http://cd.textfiles.com/pcmedic/utils/io_mouse/) (see file listing at ../../menu/io_mouse.txt ; I can't put a direct hyperlink there because I've only recently registered so I'm limited to only 2 links total).  I can't 100% vouch for the software there, but vague memory suggests to me that WhatPort may be good for detecting COM ports.

If you want more, please elaborate (like describing just what hardware you're looking for).  Otherwise, there you go.

Answer (score 0):

In the DOS days there where a bunch of 3rd party tools for DOS available that did a hardware scan and showed some system information. Many where distributed as shareware.

Here is a list:

- checkIt!
- DRHARDWARE (still available to buy for Retro PCs)
- HWINFO (also called Hardware Info, FreeWare today)
- sysinfo
- PC Analyser
- Peak Computing CINFO
- RudiSoft RSInfo
- SysChk
- TestIT

Microsoft shipped a Tool called Microsoft Diagnostics (MSD) with MS-DOS 6.x.
IBM shipped QCONFIG with PC DOS 6.x (IBM DOS).
And Norton Utilities did also have a system information and diagnostic functionality.

Hint 1: If you can't find them as shareware on the Internet, you can find many of them as shareware version on older sharware CD-ROM collections or on [archive.org](https://archive.org).

Hint 2:
Since these diagnostic tools perform very complex functions, they may not run in some virtual machines or emulators and crash. (i tested some of them in QEMU version 7)

Answer (score -1):

In the case you mean `cmd` when you say `DOS`
type the following into at the prompt

```
systeminfo
```

you can also launch a GUI version of the tool by typing `msinfo32` at the prompt

For difference between DOS and cmd see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/451432/are-the-command-prompt-and-ms-dos-the-same-thing)

**Edit**
Slightly changed the wording for people who landed here looking cmd instead of DOS

Comment: I mean a really DOS system, there's no Windows available.

Comment: have you checked if systeminfo works ?

Comment: -1 for pretending that he meant something else and answering the wrong question. You should be answering the question asked. This is a question and answer database not a help site. And besides, he actually DID mean what he asked. So by answering something else, you're doubly wrong.

Comment: @barlop yea, that was wrong speculation on my part - a lot of people mistake between the two, and hence the clarification before answering.
I will still leave this answer here , in case someone lands here who actually has the misconception.

Comment: @barlop Please try to extend to other users the courtesy of good faith. In the absence of specific information to the contrary, assuming DOS means cmd.exe seems like a fair assumption to make, those two are often used interchangeably.

Comment: A quick search lead me to the [Microsoft Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491007.aspx) article about the command. Although the info in it refers to Windows XP as a baseline, I don't seem to have it in Home Edition.

Comment: @Indrek If you think he meant something other than what he asked, then you should -still- answer the question he asked, but then add that if he meant something else, you answer for that as a side note. But first and foremost you should answer what he asked, even if you think he probably made a mistake. As I say, it's not a help site it's a QnA database.

Comment: @barlop Not sure what you're trying to say — Super User *is* all about helping people by getting answers to their questions.

Comment: The 2nd sentence of Indrek's highly-upvoted comment is still only write because of the weasel language ("seems", "are often used"). They are not properly interchangeable. DOS does not include Windows NT's CMD.EXE. The hovertext of the MS-DOS tag specifically says this is not "about Windows command line". Trying to appease CMD-seekers has the negative side effect of blurring a proper distinction between MS-DOS (which uses up far less system requirements) and the Microsoft Windows environment, which are different environments. (Keep in mind, some people don't prefer the MS Windows environment.)