# Invoking a DOS application remotely

Tags: windows, windows-xp, command-line, remote

An XP and a Win10 PC reside on a LAN.  The goal: the Win10 PC executes a program on the XP box:

```
XP_BOX>> myProgram.exe  arg1 arg2 argN
```

Is there a built-in Win10 command that enables:

```
Win10>>  remoteExecute  XP_BOX:userID:password "myProgram.exe  arg1 arg2 argN"
```

Once this works, the Win10 box has an application that can bang-out to the Win10 OS and perform remote program execution.

If there is a better way of accomplishing the above: suggestions are appreciated.  Thank you

Comment: how is DOS related here? I only see XP and win 10. If you're talking about console applications then [they're **not** DOS](http://superuser.com/q/451432/241386)

Comment: I think the OP is making the common mistake of confusing the Command Prompt with MS-DOS.