# How to pass along a filename as an argument in a .BAT file call

Tags: command-line, batch-file, dosbox

I've been doing some mucking around with DOSbox lately, and one particular task I've been doing is setting up a series of batch files for calling things so that I can save a few `cd`s.  A typical .bat file might look like the following:

```
cd wolf3d
wolf3d -goobers
cd ..
```

One thing that's become a bit annoying is the lack of a built-in text editor that I can use, such as pico/nano.  That said, I *do* have QBASIC installed, so one option I was considering was setting up so I could do a call such as the following:

```
nano filename.bat
```

and it would open up the file in QBASIC.

I've done a bit of reading on how batch scripting works, and it appears that just adding a `%1` to the script should suffice, such as the following:

```
cd qbasic
qbasic %1
cd ..
```

What ends up happening, however, is if I type in, say `nano nano.bat` so I can edit the batch file, it ends up opening up a new, blank `nano.bat` file instead.

I've tried to look up what I'm missing here, but this seems to be a bit too arcane to locate easily.  Can anyone point out what's missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: [DOS and Windows cmd are not the same thing](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386). Hence the many things are also different https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/

Comment: If you change the current directory in the batch you have to supply drive:\path\name.ext as an argument, otherwise Qbasic can't find the file and creates a new one in the now current folder

Comment: @LotPings When calling it, I've been using the path relative to the script, figuring that even though there's a `cd` in the file it would still catch the right path when getting the initial variable value.  So I guess you're suggesting something like `qbasic ..\%1` for the second line?  I'm not in a place to test that right this moment, but once I get back to my desk I'll give it a shot.  It definitely makes a lot of sense, now that you point it out.

Comment: @LotPings That did it!  If you could please repost your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate a bit more as in my comment:

- If passing a relative path as an argument to a batch which itself changes the current folder will fail if the pass isn't relative to the new folder.
- Alternatively pass an absolute pass
- or don't change the current folder if not absolutely necessary. Qbasic is a standalone `.exe` file which can be somewhere reachable via the path. To use it as an editor there is an `/Editor` option (just checked it in VDOS Plus - a DosBOX derivate)

So change your nano.bat to

```
@Qbasic.exe /Editor %1
```

provided Qbasic.exe is reachable via a folder in the path.

Answer (score 0):

Try double percents ie %%1. Batch files in dos do not quite follow the same rules for parameters as their dos shell equivalents.

Comment: That ended up opening a blank `%1.BAS` file in QBASIC.  I tried reducing it to just %1 and that produced `NANO.BAT` this time around, however it's a new blank file, instead of the one that we're trying to update.  `qbasic ../nano.bat`, however, does open the file properly, if I want to first go into `/qbasic`.

Comment: Funny that it's opening a file called nano.bas. Makes me wonder if %1 in dos box is not the first argument to the batch job but the name of the batch job itself. What happens if you use %2?

Comment: Slight correction, it's creating a blank `nano.baT`, not `.baS`; my mistake in the opening post.  Changing it to `%2` results in no file being created, just like a simple `qbasic` launch.