# Windows 10 - permanently change keyboard settings for cmd window

Tags: windows-10, command-line, keyboard-layout

I have this windows 10 pro keyboard setting problem.

My pc is a japanese laptop that I changed to a German keyboard setting.

This works OK for all windows software, but when I start a command window
by running **cmd.exe**, it's stuck on japanese, displaying the mostly English ASCII characters printed on the keyboard.

I can then type **intl.cpl** and a window with the language selection
pops up. This already shows the German language selected. After I close this
window, the keyboard works as expected.

I have to do this every time I run **cmd.exe**.

Is there a change to make this permanent - or at least change the
setting in a way that doesn't require another window popping up?

Comment: [Are the Command Prompt and MS-DOS the same thing?](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386) [Windows cmd is *NOT* DOS](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Comment: Yes, I mean when I run cmd.exe to get a prompt. I'll change the question to make this clearer.