# Windows 10 DOS editor colors with /B (monochrome) are scrambled

Tags: windows-10, command-line, colors, editing

I have Windows 10 on a Lenovo X61 PC. I have a desktop shortcut to Command Prompt with color options set to grey text / black background. I run the editor using >EDIT /B filename. For a year this gave me white text / black background for both command lines and the editor window. Now suddenly the editor window has grey text on a red background. It also has a red border and red text on the tool bar, with or without the /B switch. I noticed that if I look at options>color on the tool bar at the top of the text being edited, the background is set to black but the displayed background is red. I would be happy to omit the /B except for the annoying bright red border.

I have spent days trying to figure this out. I ran a Windows 10 check of system files and boot setup. I ran a hard drive test. I cleaned the registry (killed Windows login - I had to repair the registry). Now I am back to exactly where I started - only problem is a bright red DOS editor background and border. BTW, the editor without the /B option gives correct text and background colors. Does anyone have any ideas about this?

Comment: [the cmd.exe in Windows is **not** DOS](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want `cmd` to open with your custom colors right? I got it to work using this batch script:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe COLOR 08
```

To make this, make a new text document anywhere and enter the above code. When saving the document, click the `Save as type:` box and replace the extension `.txt` with `.bat`

If you want to use the desktop shortcut method, type this after the path to `cmd.exe`:

```
COLOR 08
```

*Ensure that there is a space before placing the command.*

Using `COLOR` at the beginning of a batch script, or as an argument will set the color at launch when running code through the command processor.

External sources:
[SS64 (Color)](https://ss64.com/nt/color.html)