# How to CD into special Windows directories under command-prompt

Tags: windows, command-line

In windows (7 & 8+) under file explorer, special Windows directories shows as really special, "`Documents`", "`Downloads`", etc, without any parent director, making it hard for people to figure out from that where they actually is. And make it hard to use such directories under DOS too:

```
C:\>cd Documents
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\>cd \Documents
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

For such special Windows directories, in there any *generic* ways to `cd` into them under DOS, without specifically using my windows ID (`c:\user\MyID`)?

Comment: When you say "DOS" do you mean something like the MS-DOS 5 operating system or do you mean something like the command-prompt window under MS Windows 10?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick, Yeah, I meant the command-prompt window under MS Windows 7,8,10. I used to call them DOS.

Comment: [the windows cmd is **not** DOS](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386) even though cmd.exe does support a few DOS commands

Comment: Fine. I changed title to ask for "_command-prompt_"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `USERPROFILE` environment variable like:

```
cd "%USERPROFILE%"\Documents
```

Comment: There has been a discussion of _another_ environment variable could _also_ be used, and also _why_ it is not the best candidate. But strangely it was covertly deleted, by someone with _extreme power_. So unhelpful and creepy.

Comment: I believe the quotation marks are unnecessary. Even if the username contains a space, the directory change will still work correctly.

Comment: @davidmneedham that may be, but I find I only get myself into trouble if I start looking for times when I can avoid quotes, and almost never get into trouble for including them.