# Why does `%errorlevel%` expand to empty string in DOSBox?

Tags: environment-variables, ms-dos, dosbox, exit-code

Trying to automate some DOSBox scripting for an old program, I wanted to use the exit code usually in `errorlevel` to control the program flow.

The input is given in a `hello_db.bat` file:

```bat
@echo off
set msg=Hello
echo %msg%
dir
echo errorlevel = %errorlevel%
```

Then DOSBox is called with `dosbox hello_db.bat`.

The output is:

```
Hello
{Listing from dir}
errorlevel =
```

So the `%errorlevel%` expanded to an empty string instead of the exit code from the `dir` command, where as the first `msg` variable could expand correctly.

How can I make DOSBox expand the `errorlevel` correctly in the script?

**Short answer based on through answer by @phuclv:**

The requirement was to insert a pause after the command if not OK (errorlevel != 0), so ended up doing:

```bat
set errorany=0
:: Command is inserted here...
if errorlevel 1 set errorany=1

:: Make pause if not OK
if %errorany%==1 pause
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `%ERRORLEVEL%` is not a variable in MS-DOS. It's DR-DOS and cmd-specific. [They're very different things](https://superuser.com/a/1411173/241386)

> ## `%ERRORLEVEL%`
>
> In COMMAND.COM of DR-DOS 7.02 and higher, this pseudo-variable returns the last error level returned by an external program or the `RETURN` command, f.e. "0".."255". See also the identically named pseudo-variable `%ERRORLEVEL%` under Windows and the `IF ERRORLEVEL` conditional command.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#DOS

Like `%DATE%` or many other variables, they're new features of cmd.exe and require [command extension](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) to be enabled

> If Command Extensions are disabled, the following dynamic variables will be not accessible:
>
> ```bat
> %CD% %DATE% %TIME% %RANDOM% %ERRORLEVEL% %CMDEXTVERSION% %CMDCMDLINE% %HIGHESTNUMANODENUMBER%
> ```
>
> https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html

If you turn off command extension for DOS compatibility you'll lose access to those variables on Windows cmd.exe

---

If you have to stick with MS-DOS and its command.com then the only way to get errorlevel is to use [`if errorlevel`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) in descending order

```bat
...
if errorlevel 4 set errorlvl=4
if errorlevel 3 set errorlvl=3
if errorlevel 2 set errorlvl=2
if errorlevel 1 set errorlvl=1
```

Fortunately if you really have to deal with all 255 error codes then you don't actually have to write 255 lines of code. But it's still rather long so see [<sup>§</sup>] below if you're interested

If you can install **alternative shells** (by setting `SHELL=\path\to\shell.com` in config.sys) then there are some 3<sup>rd</sup> party shells with an errorlevel variable. For example [the famous 4DOS has `%_?`](https://www.4dos.info/4batfaq.htm)

> Most internal 4DOS commands set errorlevel values. 4DOS has internal variables for external program exit code (`%?`), reason for external program termination (`%??`), exit code last internal command (`%_?`) and last DOS error (`%_SYSERR`). Since 4DOS is able to determine values equal, less than, less or equal, greater, greater or equal, unequal to another value, it's easy to catch specific errors:
>
> ```bat
> IF "%_?" NE "" GOSUB ERR_HANDLER
> :ERR_HANDLER
> IF %_? == 1 ...
> IF %_? == 2 ...
> ...
> RETURN
> ```
>
> The `ON ERROR...` command is also available to catch (and recover from) errors.

---

<sup>§</sup> How to check for every possible errorlevel:

```bat
@ECHO OFF
REM Reset variables
FOR %%A IN (1 10 100) DO SET ERR%%A=

REM Check error level hundredfolds
FOR %%A IN (0 1 2) DO IF ERRORLEVEL %%A00 SET ERR100=%%A
IF %ERR100%==2 GOTO 200
IF %ERR100%==0 IF NOT "%1"=="/0" SET ERR100=

REM Check error level tenfolds
FOR %%A IN (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) DO IF ERRORLEVEL %ERR100%%%A0 SET ERR10=%%A
IF "%ERR100%"=="" IF %ERR10%==0 SET ERR10=

:1
REM Check error level units
FOR %%A IN (0 1 2 3 4 5) DO IF ERRORLEVEL %ERR100%%ERR10%%%A SET ERR1=%%A
REM Modification necessary for errorlevels 250+
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 250 FOR %%A IN (6 7 8 9) DO IF ERRORLEVEL %ERR100%%ERR10%%%A SET ERR1=%%A
GOTO End

:200
REM In case of error levels over 200 both
REM tenfolds and units are limited to 5
REM since the highest DOS error level is 255
FOR %%A IN (0 1 2 3 4 5) DO IF ERRORLEVEL 2%%A0 SET ERR10=%%A
IF ERR10==5 FOR %%A IN (0 1 2 3 4 5) DO IF ERRORLEVEL 25%%A SET ERR1=%%A
IF NOT ERR10==5 GOTO 1

:End
REM Clean up the mess and show results
SET ERRORLEV=%ERR100%%ERR10%%ERR1%
FOR %%A IN (1 10 100) DO SET ERR%%A=
ECHO ERRORLEVEL  %ERRORLEV%
```

Credit: https://www.robvanderwoude.com/errorlevel.php

Comment: Thanks a lot for the through answer; that is greatly appreciated :-)  I have added a condensed solution to my question, to make it easier to apply for other that drop by.

Answer (score 1):

You should not attempt to use `%ERRORLEVEL%`, as that is more recent than DOS, as @phuclv states. Instead, use the older `IF ERRORLEVEL n` construct, which tests for whether the error level is *n* **or greater**. This means that you should test possible error levels in *descending* order:

```
IF ERRORLEVEL 5 ...  
IF ERRORLEVEL 4 ...  
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 ...
...
```

You should read the section on Detecting Errorlevel at [Errorlevel at SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html), paying specific attention to the beginning where it discusses compatibility with DOS.