# How to use special characters from bat file in windows

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

I need to open browser with special url that contains special characters (diacritics). For example "è" in url:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "https://google.com/search?q=Mèxico"
```

I could use urlencode, e.g. "https://google.com/search?q=M%C3%A8xico" but is it possible to do without escaping because it's the user who generate the bat. Something like @this_bat_uses_utf8 or something like that. Thanks.

The following code is returning empty string:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "string=Trois-Rivières, QC"
:: Define simple macros to support JavaScript within batch
set "beginJS=mshta "javascript:code(close(new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).Write("
set "endJS=)));""
:: FOR /F does not need pipe
for /f "tokens=" %%N in (
  '%beginJS% encodeURIComponent("%string%") %endJS%'
) do set encoded=%%N
echo %string% -^> %encoded%
```

Example 2: this not work, remove the è and it will start working

```
setlocal
chcp 65001 >nul
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe" --app="https://google.com/search?q=Trois-Rivières,QC"
```

Comment: [cmd in Windows is **not** DOS](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386), why do you tag DOS here?

Comment: Example 2: replace the '=' by a space, then it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such directive for batch.

The most you can do is use `chcp 65001` for UTF-8 and prepend a
[UTF-8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)
to the `.bat` file.

For implementing `urlencode` in batch, see the script from a
[StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35187347/165358):

```
@echo off
setlocal

setlocal
set "string=Trois-Rivières, QC"
:: Define simple macros to support JavaScript within batch
set "beginJS=mshta "javascript:code(close(new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).Write("
set "endJS=)));""
:: FOR /F does not need pipe
for /f "usebackq" %%N in (
  `%beginJS% encodeURIComponent('%string%') %endJS%`
) do set "encoded=%%N"
echo %string% -^> %encoded%
```

Comment: You can modify the behavior of the [for /f command](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) by adding the `tokens=` parameter to exclude blanks as separators.

Comment: There was a small error in the StackOverflow answer, which I fixed above (with your example data). Blanks are not a problem, since they are converted to the non-blank `%20`, so `tokens=` is finally not required. I have tested the example and it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a batch file that runs your code directly without any third party tools.

Store this code in a batch file encoded in UTF8 without BOM (when you have a BOM you should have an empty line at the top).

```
@echo off
setlocal

REM remeber the current code page
for /f "tokens=3 delims=:. " %%d in ('chcp') do set "_OLD_CP_=%%d"

REM set the code page to UTF8
chcp 65001 >nul

REM do the actual work (remove the 'start ""' if you want to wait for the end of the task)
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "https://google.com/search?q=Mèxico"

REM restore the old code page (if needed)
chcp %_OLD_CP_% >nul
```

Comment: This doesn't work for backward long e, see example 2

Comment: Indeed it does work (see comment for example 2). UTF8 is full Unicode character set. When one character like 'è' works, any other character should work too.

Answer (score 0):

```bath
@echo off 
 
>nul chcp 65001 & color 
for /f delims^= %%i in ('
powershell -nOp -c """$([uri]::EscapeDataString('Mèxico'))"""
   ')do "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "https://google.com/search?q=%%~i"
```

---

- Porting your reference code for use with **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)**

```bath
@echo off 

>nul chcp 65001 & color 
for /f delims^= %%i in ('
powershell -nOp -c """$([uri]::EscapeDataString('Trois-Rivières, QC'))"""
   ')do <con: echo\%%~i && set "_string=%%~i" && echo\%%~i>.\My_Output_File.log
```

- Output:

```bath
Trois-Rivi%C3%A8res%2C%20QC
```

- Online decoded:

[image]

---

- PowerShell one liner:

```bath
  $str="https://google.com/search?q=" + [uri]::EscapeDataString("Mèxico"); Start-Process -FilePath  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" $str
```