# Pass password variable to manage-dbe

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe

I need a batch program .bat to pass prompted password to `manage-bde -unlock -pw.`

Tried this unlock.bat  with password devel!

```
@ECHO OFF
:GetID
set "id="
set /P id=Enter id:
cmd /k manage-bde -unlock  K: -pw %id%
ERROR: Invalid Syntax.
"devel!" was not understood.
Type "manage-bde -?" for usage.
```

Comment: Your batch file **doesn't run in DOS**. [DOS and Windows cmd are very different](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386)!!! Don't call Windows cmd DOS. And it's batch, not  bash

Answer (score 1):

#### ERROR: Invalid Syntax.

You need quotes around the command:

```
cmd /k "manage-bde -unlock  K: -pw %id%"
```

> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> CMD [charset] [options] [/K Command] 
>
> Command : The command, program or batch script to be run.
>           This can even be several commands separated with '&' 
>           (the whole should also be surrounded by "quotes")
> ```

Source: [CMD.exe (Command Shell) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [CMD.exe (Command Shell) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) - Start a new CMD shell and (optionally) run a command/executable program.