# Need help echoing audio sound cards to a text file in a dos bat

Tags: ffmpeg, batch-file, ms-dos

I have 8 sound cards installed and am trying to create dos code to dummy echo all the sound card exact names to text file.  But `ffmpeg` won't echo output to a file .

Here is what I have tried, and not doing what it is supposed to do:

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy>>SoundCardName%batnum%.txt
```

it just lists.

Also, this doesn't work, and only lists the first sound card:

```
@For /f tokens^=1^,2delims^=^" %%a in (
'ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy 2^>^&1 ^| findstr /c:"audio"'
) do (
   if not defined AudioDevice (
      set "AudioDevice=%%~b"
      Echo "%AudioDevice%">>SoundCardName%batnum%.txt

   )
)
```

I need all 8 sound cards listed.

I don't know what `2^>^&1` means.

I don't know what `| findstr /c:"audio"'` does.  I always see pipe as something that should be or, but more likely is piping to something, in this case, I don't know.

Anyway.  Why cant I simply `>>` the output to a file, that is shown in the dos box?

Comment: You have not set `batnum` to anything.

Comment: And when you do you need to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and `!batnum!`

Comment: don't tag MS-DOS and don't call this "DOS bat". [Things like `for /f` or code blocks like that don't exist at all in DOS](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386)

Answer (score 0):

```bat
@echo off & cd /d "%~dp0"

set "_cnt=1"
set "_ffmpeg=C:\Program Files\ffmepg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"
set "_arg=-hide_banner -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy"

for /l %%L in (01,01,0%_cnt%)do if defined _AuDev_%%~L 1>nul =;(
     set "_AuDev_%%~L=" & del /q /f /a "AuDev_%%~L.txt" 2>&1 );=

for /f usebacktokens^=2delims^=^" %%i in (`^<con: 2^>^&1 ^<nul ^
     "%_ffmpeg%" %_arg% ^| %__AppDir__%findstr.exe /e .*audio^)`
     )do call set "_AuDev_%%_cnt%%=%%~i" & call set /a "_cnt+=1"
```

---

- Or, if you want to list filename and content at runtime:

```bat
@echo off & cd /d "%~dp0"

set "_cnt=1"
set "_ffmpeg=C:\Program Files\ffmepg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"
set "_arg=-hide_banner -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy"

for /l %%L in (01,01,0%_cnt%)do if defined _AuDev_%%~L 1>nul =;(
     set "_AuDev_%%~L=" & del /q /f /a "AuDev_%%~L.txt" 2>&1 );=

for /f usebacktokens^=2delims^=^" %%i in (`^<con: 2^>^&1 ^<nul ^
     "%_ffmpeg%" %_arg% ^| %__AppDir__%findstr.exe /e .*audio^)`
     )do call set "_AuDev_%%_cnt%%=%%~i" & call set /a "_cnt+=1"

for /l %%L in (01,01,0%_cnt%)do @if defined _AuDev_%%~L 2>&1 =;(
     %ComSpec% /v /c "echo\!_AuDev_%%~L!>.\"AuDev_%%~L.txt"" );=
 
for /f useback^tokens^=*delims^= %%i in (`dir /b /on AuDev_*.txt
    `)do cd.| set /p "'=File: .\%%~nxi # Device: " & type "%%~i"
```

- Outputs:

```bat
File: .\AuDev_1.txt # Device: Microfone (Conexant SmartAudio HD)
File: .\AuDev_2.txt # Device: CABLE Output (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)
```

---

## Some further reading:

- **[`If /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)**
- **[`Cd /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)**
- **[`Popd /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/popd.html)**
- **[`Find /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)**
- **[`FindStr /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)**
- **[`For Loop /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html)**
- **[`For /F Loop /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**
- **[Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

  - **[`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**
- **[Commands Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)**

  - **`|`**, **`<`**, **`>`**, **`2>`**, **`2>&1`**, etc.