# Batch rename in DOS

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I have over 1000 files with the following format

```
WMS_002248557A931EDE81AEE9DEF8AB0CCD.xml.20230607T141028.383-1443092915
WMS_0022485689451EDE81AEFD441B115F0C.xml.20230607T141430.753-1443334398
```

I want to keep ONLY up to XML and stripped the rest

how can I do this in DOS Command prompt?

I have tried the following command

```
ren *.xml.* *.xml
```

and the result is close but not exactly how I want it

```
WMS_002248557A931EDE81AEE9DEF8AB0CCD.xml.20230607T141028.xml
WMS_0022485689451EDE81AEFD441B115F0C.xml.20230607T141430.xml
```

Comment: DOS doesn't support such file names. Don't call it "DOS" when you're using the Windows cmd which is [entirely different](https://superuser.com/a/1411173/241386)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out
since the length of the filename prefix (WMS_) 4 chars and guid (32 chars) is constant

there is 36 question marks here.

```
ren *.* ??????????????????????????????????????.xml
```

and the output is exactly what I need. Thanks

```
WMS_002248557A931EDE81AEE9DEF8AB0CCD.xml
WMS_0022485689451EDE81AEFD441B115F0C.xml
```